# View-Based Application? - Please explain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, applet

XCode: "This template provides a starting point for an application that uses a single view. It provides a view controller to manage the view, and a nib file that contains the view."

What does that even mean? (ie what does Single view actually mean)

1) This means that your application will only have a single view screen that is active

2) This means that your application will be able to have as many screens as you like using a single view controller.

Ok now what if your application has multiple screens? not a single view screen, is still suitable under a view based application template?

**Example**

Screen1(main): on this screen you have 3 buttons, "Open Form1", "Open Form2", "Open Form3"

When the button is clicked it opens up the associated screen,

Press the "Open Form1" button opens up "Form1" screen2

Press the "Open Form2" button opens up "Form2" screen3

Press the "Open Form3" button opens up "Form3" screen4

When the user completes the form and submits it, a thank you screen is displayed
therefore in this example there would be a total of 5 screens.

Each form screen contains is different, textfield inputs, and information, is this considered as a view based application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View-based app is just a template to say that your app will be view-based. That means that you can have any number of views you want, as this template comes with a view controller (that, as the name says, can be used to control the views... show/hide them with animation, for example).

The template starts with ONE VIEW that is added to the app view controller. You can add any number of views to that controller.

So, yes to your questions. You can use this to create the app you mention, where any of the "screens" you mention would be a view, for example and you can show each one using, for instance, the app view controller to animate each view showing or hiding.

Comment: thanks. Ok whats the differences between a view-based application and a windows based application? I read the description but i still do not understand the different clearly.

Comment: A window-base app template will not come with a view controller, for example.  These are just templates. You can use any template to create any kind of app you want. Choosing one will not forbid an application from doing something. In some cases, choosing a window base app can be desired, if for example, you will have just one view on your application (you don't need a view controller in this case).

Answer (score 2):

That means the template will create one view and corresponding view controller along with app delegate, main window. That will also do the necessary things to add this view to main windows, and load when app runs. This is just a template. Then you can crate any number of views and view controllers as you want.

Comment: Do you need to create a new controller for each and every screen? (I assume I can use 1 controller to control multiple screens, yes?no?)

Comment: Yes, you can do that but not suggested unless the views are very primitive.

Comment: what if the screens are related? Scree1 (input information), Screen2 (Review and confirm Information), Screen3 (thank you response). There should be 3 controllers or just 1 controller in this case?

Comment: In this particular example I will prefer one controller as they are closely related and not very complex. But say there is main menu, a separate form, a terms and conditions screen and a detail description view. For these I will use separate controllers. Other people can choose otherwise. These decision will largely depend on various factors like size, scalability of project, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the template you are starting the project with provides a single ViewController, and associated XIB for the View. As the first answer says you could use this template to build the application mentioned.

HOWEVER you may wish to think about how the user is going to interact with your app. Will you allow stepping back and forwards through the screens, in which case you may want to consider the Navigation Based app where you push/pop screens onto a stack to allow easy movement between then.

You might also have a concept of allowing the user to jump at will between each of the screen pages in which case you might want to implement a TabBar application.

Or you could just implement it all yourself. At the end of the day it will be your application design, and the template is only a starting point to get you going. I would suggest that if you are starting out with iOS development however to go with 1 ViewController matched a XIB for each screen you wish to implement to keep things simple.

---

Comment: Also when you create multiple screens, will each screen require a viewcontroller for each screen that you create? Or can a viewcontroller be used to control more than 1 screen.